# server.htmldecode working on localhost but it does not work when pushed live c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, decode

I asked a question about Server.HtmlDecode(string) about a week ago, [HtmlDecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472707/html-decoding-from-sql-server-to-microsoft-word?noredirect=1#comment70151719_41472707). I was able to get it working correctly on my localhost. I pushed everything to the live website I am still getting the same issue I was having before. `&nbsp;` is still being stored in the SQL Database.

This is the code that is supposed to decode the text box strings and insert them into a new table in the database. Again, this is working as expected when I am debugging.

```
private void createInvoiceQueue()
{
    string db = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LakeEncroManSys"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(db))
    {
        using (SqlCommand querycmd = new SqlCommand("Select Count(*) from tblInvprintqueue", conn))
        {
            querycmd.Connection.Open();
            int sqlResult = (int)querycmd.ExecuteScalar();
            querycmd.Connection.Close();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand ExecSP = new SqlCommand("spCreateInvoicePrintQueue", conn);
                ExecSP.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                ExecSP.Connection.Open();
                sdr = ExecSP.ExecuteReader();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    lblError.Visible = true;
                    lblError.Text = "Invoices are being created.";
                }
                ExecSP.Connection.Close();
            }
            catch (System.Exception excep)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excep.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
                    if (GridView1.Visible)
                    {
                        SqlCommand insertInvoice = new SqlCommand("Insert into tblInvPrintQueue ([InvoiceNumber],[EncID],[EncType],[ParcelID],[AmountDue],[DateInvoice],[DateDue],[NumSlips],[FullName],[Addr1],[Addr2],[Addr3],[Note],[PermitYear]) " +
                            "Values (@InvNum,@EncID,@EncType,@ParcelID,@AmountDue,@DateInv,@DateDue,@NumSlips,@FullName,@Addr1,@Addr2,@Addr3,@Note,@PermitYear)", conn);
                        insertInvoice.Connection.Open();
                        insertInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvNum", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[0].Text);
                        insertInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EncID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[1].Text);
                        insertInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EncType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[2].Text);
                        insertInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParcelID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[3].Text);
                        insertInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AmountDue", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[4].Text);
                        insertInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateInv", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[5].Text);
                        insertInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateDue", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[6].Text);
                        insertInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumSlips", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[7].Text);
                        insertInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[8].Text);
                        insertInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addr1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[9].Text);
                        insertInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addr2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[10].Text);
                        insertInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addr3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[11].Text);
                        insertInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[12].Text);
                        insertInvoice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PermitYear", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DateTime.Parse(LeaseYear).Year;
                        insertInvoice.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        insertInvoice.Connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: &nbsp will not get converted to anything else using HTMLDecode because it isn't a valid HTML token. It is missing the trailing semicolon. Also, you might want to take a peek at this article since you are using AddWithValue in adhoc queries. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @SeanLange &nbsp; is stored in the database. I missed the semicolon on my question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue I was having. It turns out there were multiple saves of the source code, and I was pushing to the wrong source code. After diving into the network drives and IIS, I was able to find the correct source code and push the fix, which is not saving the HTML character codes.